# Getting data from selected item in QListView

Tags: python, pyqt

I populate a QListView with QSqlTableModel.

```
  projectModel = QSqlTableModel()
  projectModel.setTable("project")
  projectModel.select()

  projectView = QListView()
  projectView.setModel(projectModel)
  projectView.setModelColumn(1)
```

- edit my wording a bit. -

Say my QSqlTableModel has 3 columns. (0) for id, (1) for name, (2) for color, for example.

In my QListView I'm displaying column 1, so only the names. Then I have 1 item selected. How can I retrieve that item's id and color?

Sorry I'm a very beginner at this. Too beginner I can't figure things out reading documentations :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Though i didn't fully understand what you are trying to do, I'm showing you the answer of your two question.

For example we have an sqlite3 database "sqlitedb.rdb"
And a table name "info",

```
CREATE TABLE info (
id integer  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT DEFAULT NULL,
name TEXT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
country TEXT(20) DEFAULT NULL,
age integer)
```

and have some data,

```
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Leroy Hale','San Marino','46');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('William Coleman','Namibia','50');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Phelan Waller','Belgium','43');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Kato Martin','Virgin Islands, British','21');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Jameson Mccoy','United Arab Emirates','45');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Fulton Reeves','Belarus','34');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Calvin Love','Morocco','28');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Peter Solis','Bhutan','31');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Connor Stephenson','Dominican Republic','26');
INSERT INTO info (name,country,age) VALUES ('Aristotle Smith','Chad','45');
```

Now,

> I only want to display the id and name (column 0 and 1) how do I do that?

To do this you can,

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel,QSqlDatabase,QSqlQuery
from PyQt4.QtGui import QTableView,QApplication
import sys

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("sqlitedb.rdb")
db.open()

projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
projectModel.setQuery("select name,age from info",db)

projectView = QTableView()
projectView.setModel(projectModel)

projectView.show()
app.exec_()
```

You can set which field/column you want to show using the query.

and,

> how can I retrieve the information from different columns of the item I have selected?

You can navigate through the result of the query and have the data, example,

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlDatabase,QSqlQuery
from PyQt4.QtCore import QCoreApplication
import sys

app = QCoreApplication(sys.argv)

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("sqlitedb.rdb")
db.open()

query = QSqlQuery()
query.exec_("select * from info")
while (query.next()):
    id = query.value(0).toInt()
    name = query.value(1).toString()
    country = query.value(2).toString()
    age = query.value(3).toInt()

    print "name = %s \ncountry = %s" % (name,country)

app.exec_()
```

you can loop through the query and get access to the data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the example Sarim. Really appreciated the setQuery example. For this particular question, I would like to know how to retrieve the data of only the selected item. I edited my question, sorry if my wording wasn't clear :)

Comment: My mistake, by 'select' you mean selected row of QListView, but i thought you mean mysql SELECT statement. I have added another answer below for QListView's select :)

Answer (score 3):

> In my QListView I'm displaying column 1, so only the names. Then I
>   have 1 item selected. How can I retrieve that item's id and color?

Please check the following example. You can add a function to the "clicked" slot of QListView. Then get the which row is selected.

```
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlDatabase,QSqlTableModel
from PyQt4.QtGui import QListView,QApplication
import sys

def listclicked(index):
    row = index.row()
    print "id = %s" % projectModel.record(row).field(0).value().toString()
    print "country = %s" % projectModel.record(row).field(2).value().toString()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
db.setDatabaseName("sqlitedb.rdb")
db.open()

projectModel = QSqlTableModel()
projectModel.setTable("info")
projectModel.select()

projectView = QListView()
projectView.setModel(projectModel)
projectView.setModelColumn(1)
projectView.clicked.connect(listclicked)
projectView.show()

app.exec_()
```

Comment: I was looking just for this answer. You are my savior for the day. Very well explained!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `selectedIndexes()` method of the model to get the indexes of the selected items using something like

```
idx = self.projectView.selectionModel().selectedRows()
```

then looping on idx, you can get the values you need with

```
for rec in idx:
    entry = rec.row()
    val = self.projectModel.record(entry).field(x).value()
```

with `x` beeing the number of the column you want to retrive

`val` is now a QVariant and you can further elaborate it.

Comment: Thanks Gianluca. My idx is turning out as an empty list however.