# PyQt4 QTableView model based

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtableview, qlistview

I am trying to display some simple info from SQLite database into QTableView. I have followed [one answer from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923562/getting-data-from-selected-item-in-qlistview), and for itself, it is working. When I try to implement the same code into my GUI (just a simple mainwindow with a QTableView object) it shows nothing. Here is the code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from gui import Ui_MainWindow
from dialog import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt4.QtSql import QSqlQueryModel,QSqlDatabase,QSqlQuery

import sys

class Glavni(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Glavni, self).__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

        #QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.actionRegistar, QtCore.SIGNAL("triggered()"), self.popup)
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName("baza.db")
        db.open()

        projectModel = QSqlQueryModel()
        projectModel.setQuery("select name from people",db)

        projectView = QtGui.QTableView()
        projectView.setModel(projectModel)
        projectView.show()

    def popup(self):
        dialog = QtGui.QDialog()
        dialog.show()

class Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Dialog,self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    prozor = Glavni()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What am I doing wrong? QListView's name in QT Designer is lista, if that is relavant. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase that;

How do I display SQLite contents in a QList or QTableView made in QT Designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
projectView = QtGui.QTableView() #THIS part is wrong if the GUI is designed through Designer
projectView.setModel(projectModel)
projectView.show()
```

the correct code is similar to this:

```
projectView = self.ui.myList #or some other name, which is the SAME AS that object name in   Designer
projectView.setModel(projectModel)
projectView.show()
```

and it works ;)