# Qt - Normal vertical scrollbar handle behavior in QTableView

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I'm using a QTableView in Qt (PyQt4, actually). The vertical scrollbar acts very weird, different than how a QTableWidget scrollbar or any other scrollbar acts. I have a large table, with thousands of rows. The handle (the clickable/draggable portion) of the vertical scrollbar always starts out larger (taller) than it should. When I use my scroll wheel to scroll down the table to the point where the handle is at about the 90% position of the scrollbar (even though I'm only say 30% through the table), the handle suddenly moves back up to say the 70% position of the scrollbar and shrinks a bit in size. As I traverse the rest of the table, the handle repeats this behavior, getting a little smaller each time and jumping back up the scrollbar to about the 70% position every time the handle gets to the bottom of the scrollbar.

Note that this strange behavior only happens when my table is pretty long (say at least 500 rows).

I appreciate that this is an interesting mechanic and makes some sense, but it must be optional. Is there some way to disable it and get a scrollbar handle which behaves normally in a long table?

All I'm doing with the QTableView is creating it and setting its model to a QSqlQueryModel which uses a basic SQL query to a database.

Comment: it's working fine for me. are you using qt4 designer or hard coding ??@Pat Flegit

Comment: Hard coding everything with PyQt4. I'm getting the data from a SQL database, and my code is nothing different than what's given in the top answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923562/getting-data-from-selected-item-in-qlistview

Comment: see this example it works fine for me

Comment: Is this dependent on QSqlQueryModel or does it happen for any large dataset? If so, could you make a minimal examplel. This articel about [tables with large datasets](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq07-big-tables.html) could also be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model only fetches the amount of data necessary for the viewport at the start. Doing this at the start fixes it:

```
model = QSqlQueryModel()
model.setQuery("select some stuff", db)
while model.canFetchMore():
    model.fetchMore()
tableView.setModel(model)
```

Answer (score -1):

this is the example i have and the scroll bar works fine

```
 import operator
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    class MyWindow(QWidget):
        def __init__(self, data_list, header, *args):
            QWidget.__init__(self, *args)
            # setGeometry(x_pos, y_pos, width, height)
            self.setGeometry(300, 200, 570, 450)
            self.setWindowTitle("Click on column title to sort")
            table_model = MyTableModel(self, data_list, header)
            table_view = QTableView()
            table_view.setModel(table_model)
            # set font
            font = QFont("Courier New", 14)
            table_view.setFont(font)
            # set column width to fit contents (set font first!)
            table_view.resizeColumnsToContents()
            # enable sorting
            table_view.setSortingEnabled(True)
            layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
            layout.addWidget(table_view)
            self.setLayout(layout)
    class MyTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
        def __init__(self, parent, mylist, header, *args):
            QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
            self.mylist = mylist
            self.header = header
        def rowCount(self, parent):
            return len(self.mylist)
        def columnCount(self, parent):
            return len(self.mylist[0])
        def data(self, index, role):
            if not index.isValid():
                return None
            elif role != Qt.DisplayRole:
                return None
            return self.mylist[index.row()][index.column()]
        def headerData(self, col, orientation, role):
            if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
                return self.header[col]
            return None
        def sort(self, col, order):
            """sort table by given column number col"""
            self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutAboutToBeChanged()"))
            self.mylist = sorted(self.mylist,
                key=operator.itemgetter(col))
            if order == Qt.DescendingOrder:
                self.mylist.reverse()
            self.emit(SIGNAL("layoutChanged()"))
    # the solvent data ...
    header = ['Solvent Name', ' BP (deg C)', ' MP (deg C)', ' Density (g/ml)']
    # use numbers for numeric data to sort properly
    data_list = [
    ('ACETIC ACID', 117.9, 16.7, 1.049),
    ('ACETIC ANHYDRIDE', 140.1, -73.1, 1.087),
    ('ACETONE', 56.3, -94.7, 0.791),
    ('ACETONITRILE', 81.6, -43.8, 0.786),
    ('ANISOLE', 154.2, -37.0, 0.995),
    ('BENZYL ALCOHOL', 205.4, -15.3, 1.045),
    ('BENZYL BENZOATE', 323.5, 19.4, 1.112),
    ('BUTYL ALCOHOL NORMAL', 117.7, -88.6, 0.81),
    ('BUTYL ALCOHOL SEC', 99.6, -114.7, 0.805),
    ('BUTYL ALCOHOL TERTIARY', 82.2, 25.5, 0.786),
    ('CHLOROBENZENE', 131.7, -45.6, 1.111),
    ('CYCLOHEXANE', 80.7, 6.6, 0.779),
    ('CYCLOHEXANOL', 161.1, 25.1, 0.971),
    ('CYCLOHEXANONE', 155.2, -47.0, 0.947),
    ('DICHLOROETHANE 1 2', 83.5, -35.7, 1.246),
    ('DICHLOROMETHANE', 39.8, -95.1, 1.325),
    ('DIETHYL ETHER', 34.5, -116.2, 0.715),
    ('DIMETHYLACETAMIDE', 166.1, -20.0, 0.937),
    ('DIMETHYLFORMAMIDE', 153.3, -60.4, 0.944),
    ('DIMETHYLSULFOXIDE', 189.4, 18.5, 1.102),
    ('DIOXANE 1 4', 101.3, 11.8, 1.034),
    ('DIPHENYL ETHER', 258.3, 26.9, 1.066),
    ('ETHYL ACETATE', 77.1, -83.9, 0.902),
    ('ETHYL ALCOHOL', 78.3, -114.1, 0.789),
    ('ETHYL DIGLYME', 188.2, -45.0, 0.906),
    ('ETHYLENE CARBONATE', 248.3, 36.4, 1.321),
    ('ETHYLENE GLYCOL', 197.3, -13.2, 1.114),
    ('FORMIC ACID', 100.6, 8.3, 1.22),
    ('HEPTANE', 98.4, -90.6, 0.684),
    ('HEXAMETHYL PHOSPHORAMIDE', 233.2, 7.2, 1.027),
    ('HEXANE', 68.7, -95.3, 0.659),
    ('ISO OCTANE', 99.2, -107.4, 0.692),
    ('ISOPROPYL ACETATE', 88.6, -73.4, 0.872),
    ('ISOPROPYL ALCOHOL', 82.3, -88.0, 0.785),
    ('METHYL ALCOHOL', 64.7, -97.7, 0.791),
    ('METHYL ETHYLKETONE', 79.6, -86.7, 0.805),
    ('METHYL ISOBUTYL KETONE', 116.5, -84.0, 0.798),
    ('METHYL T-BUTYL ETHER', 55.5, -10.0, 0.74),
    ('METHYLPYRROLIDINONE N', 203.2, -23.5, 1.027),
    ('MORPHOLINE', 128.9, -3.1, 1.0),
    ('NITROBENZENE', 210.8, 5.7, 1.208),
    ('NITROMETHANE', 101.2, -28.5, 1.131),
    ('PENTANE', 36.1, ' -129.7', 0.626),
    ('PHENOL', 181.8, 40.9, 1.066),
    ('PROPANENITRILE', 97.1, -92.8, 0.782),
    ('PROPIONIC ACID', 141.1, -20.7, 0.993),
    ('PROPIONITRILE', 97.4, -92.8, 0.782),
    ('PROPYLENE GLYCOL', 187.6, -60.1, 1.04),
    ('PYRIDINE', 115.4, -41.6, 0.978),
    ('SULFOLANE', 287.3, 28.5, 1.262),
    ('TETRAHYDROFURAN', 66.2, -108.5, 0.887),
    ('TOLUENE', 110.6, -94.9, 0.867),
    ('TRIETHYL PHOSPHATE', 215.4, -56.4, 1.072),
    ('TRIETHYLAMINE', 89.5, -114.7, 0.726),
    ('TRIFLUOROACETIC ACID', 71.8, -15.3, 1.489),
    ('WATER', 100.0, 0.0, 1.0),
    ('XYLENES', 139.1, -47.8, 0.86)
    ]
    app = QApplication([])
    win = MyWindow(data_list, header)
    win.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: This works fine for me too. As it turns out, so does my original query when I only have a few dozen results. It's when I have say 500 rows that the alternate behavior arises. I updated the original post with this info.